# Normalising Data in R - I keep getting an error

Tags: r

I keep getting an error when i am trying to normalise my data in R.
I'm using this code:

```
normalize<-function(x){
return((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
}

breastcancer<-as.data.frame(lapply(breastcancer[,c(1,2,3,4,5,,6,7,8,9,10,11)],normalize)
```

and the error i get is:

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(7L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 10L,  : 
‘min’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: It seems that at least one of the columns from `breastcancer` that you pick are factor. Run `sapply(breastcancer[,c(1,2,3,4,5,,6,7,8,9,10,11)], is.factor)` to find them.

Comment: You can use a colon to create a sequence `1:11`